# 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord.py

I’ve been tormented by this error for a week, I seriously don’t understand what’s the matter, help plz
'int' object has no attribute 'id'
there is my code:

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio
from discord import Member
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import check
from discord.ext.commands import has_role

ROLE = 730459135170183170
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_role(730459135170183170)
async def use_shovel(ctx,user: discord.Member):
     x = random.randint(1,50)
     role = get(user.guild.roles, name =ROLE)
     if x == 1:
         await ctx.send("You've found REQUIEM ARROW!")
         await bot.author.add_roles(731166197030322216)
     else:
         await ctx.send("meh, nothing")
         await user.remove_roles(731166197030322216)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "use_shove" is not found

Ignoring exception in command use_shovel:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "meh.py", line 24, in use_shovel
    await user.remove_roles(731166197030322216)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 685, in remove_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I really cannot understand why this error happen. So,how can I fix this?I

Comment: The code is incomplete, it doesn't include the part referenced in the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code :

- First, you're looking for a role with `730459135170183170` as a name, so your `role` variable's value will be `None`.

```py
ROLE = 730459135170183170
(...)
role = get(user.guild.roles, name =ROLE)
```

- Then, both [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add%20roles#discord.Member.add_roles) and [`remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove%20roles#discord.Member.remove_roles) take a [`role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role) object as argument, not an `int`.

```py
await bot.author.add_roles(731166197030322216)
(...)
await user.remove_roles(731166197030322216)
```

- Finally, never ever share your token on any website:

```
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

You should go to your discord bot app and create a new token, so you're the only one who can use your bot app.

To solve your problem, you can get rid of your `ROLE` variable and replaces these lines:

```py
@commands.has_role("Exact role name")
(...)
role = get(user.guild.roles, name="Exact role name")
(...)
await bot.author.add_roles(role)
(...)
await user.remove_roles(role)
```